# Light Switch 3-wire but with 2 permanent lives

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

Trying to wire a Fibaro dimmer into this light switch but not having much luck. There appears to be 2 permanent lives coming into the COM port and the presumed switched live out of L1 port. I can't find anything on Internet for why 2 permanent lives should be there. I can't wire both these lives into L terminal of the dimmer as it can't fit 2 cables. This is not a two way switch- it's just one switch for 3 lights. 
Thanks
Andy

[image]

Comment: It could be that there are two "live" wires because one feeds power to the switch box from the panel and the other is a continuation to feed power on to another electrical box. If this is the case you should connect them together along with a pigtail which then goes to the switch assembly.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Do you know if this is still possible with the fibaro dimmer?

Comment: Sorry but I know little to nothing about the Fibaro dimmer. You may have to offer up a picture of the dimmer or provide a link to an online instruction sheet for your particular dimmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 3-way wire connector of the type customary in your area to attach a pigtail (short piece of wire of the same gauge as the rest) to the two existing hot (live) wires, and then hook the pigtail up to the dimmer's common input.

Michael Karas' explanation is the most likely one, by the way -- it looks like whoever installed this switch was being a bit hackish or didn't have the extra wire connector and pigtail at hand, so they simply twisted the two wires together and stuffed them into the backstab common terminal on the switch.